# How to convert correctly only time in dart

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart, datetime-format

i've a string like this

```
String time = '13:00:00Z'; (Zulu time)
```

I want to convert it into a string in the correct local time.
For example if i execute the program, i want 15:00 as a result because 13:00 in my local time it's 15:00.

I get the error "FormatExeption: Invalid date format", whatever I put in the DateFormat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prepend current date to the time string and then use `toLocal()` to convert it to your local time:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.now();
String formattedDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(date);
String time = "13:00:00Z";
DateTime dt = DateTime.parse(formattedDate + "T" + time).toLocal();
String formattedTime = DateFormat('HH:mm').format(dt);
print(formattedTime);
```

(`DateFormat` is from the [intl package](https://pub.dev/packages/intl))